# How do I create a transparent form with solid controls in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

OK, so I know of two slightly different ways to create a transparent form with solid controls in VB.NET - the trouble is that both have a different flaw.

```
Me.BackColor = Nothing
TransparencyKey = BackColor
```

This code enables me to click on items behind my form that are in areas I have left transparent. But any scroll bars on my form adopt the transparent background so they look ugly and cannot be clicked on because I would be clicking on the item behind my form.

```
Me.BackColor = Color.Azure
TransparencyKey = Color.Azure
```

This code solves the scroll bar problem - but now I can no longer click on any items behind my form in the areas I have left transparent. The form is transparent but has become solid.

So what I'm after is the best of both worlds. My scroll bars obviously need to be solid as in the second option, but items behind my form in areas I have left transparent need to be clickable, as in the first option.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: `Me.BackColor = Color.Magenta TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta`

Comment: Setting the color to Nothing actually sets it to 0.  Which is Black with an alpha of 0.  Aka Color.Transparent.  You never want to make black the transparency key, making text transparent is a fairly inevitable next mishap.  Color.Fuschia and Color.Lime are very good choices, far too ugly to cause accidental matches.

Comment: Of course, whatever of these Colors (among the ugliest for an UI :) you choose, you want to set the TransparencyKey in the Form Designer and `BackColor = TransparencyKey` in the Form Constructor, because if someone sees a Form colored like that, that someone may think you should not be allowed to build GUIs :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments Hans & Jimi. Your suggestion though is the same as my second option, except I used Azure. The problem is that the transparent areas are like closed windows - I can't then click on items behind my form. In the first of my options the transparent areas are like open windows - I can click on items behind my form, but I get the ugly scroll bars. What I want is to be able to click on items behind my form but no ugly scroll bars. If necessary I guess I could make my own scroll bars but that would be a hassle and I imagine there must be an easier way of achieving this.

Comment: Not at all. `Color.Magenta`, `Color.Fuchsia` and `Color.Lime` cause the Form to present a *non-solid* transparent background (you can click through it), but none of the Controls is affected. Scrollbars included. `Color.Azure`, as almost all *blue-ish* colors, generates a *solid* transparent background.

Comment: I do apologise! I assumed you read the question wrong and that if Color.Azure didn't work then neither would other colours - but I was wrong! Using Color.Lime works perfectly, thank you.